# Loss of Serial Port in Application

Tags: c#, serial-port

I recently built a serial port communication application and am looking for a way to handle an exception in the event that a serial port is lost while the app is running. For example if my serial cable became disconnected during use of the application my app would crash. What is a good way to handle this issue?

Comment: That doesn't cause an exception.  Serial ports are far too primitive to have anything like a "device was lost" kind of failure mode.  The DsrHolding and CtsHolding properties will turn off, that's all.  Disconnecting the USB cable of an emulator, that will produce a loud bang in many cases.  USB drivers in general do not deal with this well, they'll make the device disappear even though you have it opened.  A bit like jerking the hard drive out of your machine without shutting down first.  Dzzz.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the event called by the class ([`SerialPort.ErrorReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) or simply catch the exception thrown and handle it.